# Recursive macro in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I've added a macro to Twig and I'm trying to get that Macro to call itself. It appears that using _self appears to now be frowned on and doesn't work, returning the error:

```
using the dot notation on an instance of Twig_Template is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0.
```

If I do import _self as x, then it works when I initially call the macro:

```
{% import _self as twigdebug %}
{{ twigdebug.recursiveTree() }}
```

But I can't then call the macro recursively using _self or twigdebug.recursiveTree.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try asking here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20568

Answer (score 18):

Example:

```
{% macro recursiveCategory(category) %}
    {% import _self as self %}
    <li>
        <h4><a href="{{ path(category.route, category.routeParams) }}">{{ category }}</a></h4>  
        {% if category.children|length %}
            <ul>
                {% for child in category.children %}
                    {{ self.recursiveCategory(child) }}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import recursiveCategory %}

<div id="categories">
    <ul>
        {% for category in categories %}
            {{ recursiveCategory(category) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Some explainations maybe?

Comment: Code should be self-explanatory... the macro is defined, then imported, then used. After first explicit call, inside the `for`, macro is calling itself recursively

Comment: It's import to note that the import is *in the macro*, not in the file itself :)

Comment: @Martijn there a double import: macro needs to import itself, then template needs to import macro

Comment: I tried the same but got a browser ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. The problem disappear when I delete the line {{ self.recursiveCategory(child) }} , but the recursivity logically doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

It is written in Twig's [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html#macro) documentation:

> Twig macros don't have access to the current template variables

You either have to `import` self in template AND in the macro as well:

```
{% macro recursiveTree() %}
    {# ... #}

    {# Import and call from macro scope #}
    {% import _self as twigdebug %}
    {{ twigdebug.recursiveTree() }}
{% endmacro %}

{# Import and call from template scope #}
{% import _self as twigdebug %}
{{ twigdebug.recursiveTree() }}
```

Or you can pass the imported `_self` object directly to the macro.

```
{% macro recursiveTree(twigdebug) %}
    {# ... #}

    {# Call from macro parameter #}
    {# and add the parameter to the recursive call #}
    {{ twigdebug.recursiveTree(twigdebug) }}
{% endmacro %}

{# Import and call from template scope #}
{% import _self as twigdebug %}
{{ twigdebug.recursiveTree(twigdebug) }}
```